# Where does Photon get his powers from?

Tags: photon

In the eponymous series, I'm rather confused as to where the protagonist gets his powers from. He is called a "singularity" more than once but the why and how and what that means exactly is rather... sketchy. On one hand he seems to be the source of his own power, and yet he also seems affected by the reconfiguration happening towards the end of the series.

Does anyone know if there's an explanation or if it's just left vague on purpose?